# Access object literal's attributes from a closure

Tags: javascript, closures, web-worker

I am trying to find a way to run a function of an object literal upon its instantiation in a Web Worker. A closure would be an awesome way to do that but it seems the closure does not have access to `Foo` (`this` always refers to worker's dedicated global context). Plus, I cannot pass or bind `Foo` to the closure because the browser would complain about accessing it before initialization.

Is there any way to modify `bar` from `init`?

p.s. I'm aware of the option of calling `Foo.init()` explicitly, but that's not my intention. I'm trying to avoid that.

```
const Foo = 
{
    bar: {},

    init: (function (){
        //Make some computations and add it to bar
        this.bar["key"] = someSpecialValue;
    })()
    //Doesn't work either:
    // })(this)
    // })().bind(this)
    // })(Foo)
}
```

Comment: The object you’re trying to modify doesn’t exist at that time yet at all. You could only run that closure *after* the object is fully defined.

Comment: Generally when you find yourself wanting the described ability, it's probably best to encapsulate the construction of the object in a function.